# How to Draw a Line at Non Integer Pixel Coordinates on an Image

Tags: image-processing, computer-graphics

I have lines (or segments really) I want to draw into a new image `I`.
Let's define the intensity of the pixel at `row = r` and `col = c` as `I(r,c)`.  However, the lines are defined by 2 points whose coordinates are not integers.

For example, one line might be from point A (with `row = 2.2` and `col = 3.5`) and to point B with (`row = 10.8` and `col = 30.4`).

What is the algorithm or method for filling in the intensity values of image `I` at the integer rows and cols?

Comment: Did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu's_line_algorithm ?

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you for mentioning this algorithm I did not know about

Comment: @Hilmar You should add that as an answer, perhaps quoting some of the text.

Answer (score 4):

A long time ago I wrote an article on drawing lines with the Wu-Line algorithm. This can be used to draw lines from non-integer coordinates. The effect is very nice to see when animated. You can still find it in the Wayback Machine:

[image: Wu-lines anti-aliased]

[Wu Anti-aliased Lines](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408133525/http://freespace.virgin.net:80/hugo.elias/graphics/x_wuline.htm) from [The good-looking textured light-sourced bouncy fun smart and stretchy page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160318230435/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/)

There's also some pseudo-code to get you started.

Comment: Isn't the wayback machine great! :-)